# tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) no funciona

Tags: ios, swift4, uitableview

Estoy desarrollando una app para IOS en Swift4. Necesito hacer un control, que simule un DropDown, para poder utilizarlo desde distintas pantallas, para ello he creado una clase en la que tengo un UIButton y un UITableView. No uso el IB.

Los datos en el UITableView se cargan perfectamente, pero quiero que al seleccionar un elemento de esa tabla, poder guardar el elemento que he seleccionado.

El problema es que, aunque está configurado el delegado del UITableView, no saltan los eventos del delegado, por ejemplo, el evento didSelectRowAt.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
@IBDesignable
public class CustomDropDown: UIView, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate  {

    let Cell_id = "cellDropDown"
    private var btnBoton: UIButton?
    private var tvListaOpciones: UITableView?
    var lstOpciones: Array<DropDownOption> = Array<DropDownOption>()
    {
        didSet
        {
            self.delegate?.change_datasource(datasource: self.lstOpciones)
            if  self.tvListaOpciones != nil
            {
                self.tvListaOpciones?.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
    internal var delegate: CustomDropDownDelegate? = nil

    override public init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setControls()
    }

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setControls()
    }

    private func setControls(){

        self.btnBoton = UIButton()
        self.btnBoton?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height)
        self.btnBoton?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnBoton_click(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.addSubview(self.btnBoton!)

        self.tvListaOpciones = UITableView()
        self.tvListaOpciones?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: (self.btnBoton?.frame.height)!, width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height + 100)
        self.tvListaOpciones?.isHidden = true

        //Estas 3 lineas son para probar si funciona (viendo información en foros)
        self.tvListaOpciones?.isEditing = false
        self.tvListaOpciones?.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = true
        self.tvListaOpciones?.allowsSelection = true 
        ////////////

        self.tvListaOpciones!.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: Cell_id)

        self.tvListaOpciones?.dataSource = self
        self.tvListaOpciones?.delegate = self 
        self.addSubview(self.tvListaOpciones!)

        self.tvListaOpciones?.reloadData()

    }


    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return lstOpciones.count
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let cell  = self.tvListaOpciones!.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Cell_id)
       cell!.textLabel!.text = ""
       if lstOpciones.count > 0
        {
           let opcion = lstOpciones[indexPath.row] as DropDownOption
            cell?.textLabel!.text = opcion.name
        }
        return cell!
    }


    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

       if lstOpciones.count > 0
        {
            let dispositivo = lstOpciones[indexPath.row] as DropDownOption
            if dispositivo != nil
            {
                self.btnBoton?.titleLabel!.text = dispositivo.name
            }

            self.tvListaOpciones!.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

        }
         self.tvListaOpciones?.isHidden = true
    }

    @objc fileprivate func btnBoton_click(sender: UIButton) {
        self.tvListaOpciones!.isHidden = !self.tvListaOpciones!.isHidden
    }

}
```

Gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Comment: Que es esto ? **self.tvListaOpciones?.delegate = self**

Comment: Con esa linea lo que se pretende es indicarle que el propio control que estoy creando es el delegado de la UITableView. Para que salte el evento que no está funcionando. ¿no es correcto eso? quizá sea el motivo por el que no funciona.. (los asteriscos es por que quería resaltar en negrita, los he quitado)

Comment: y pasa por el método del didSelectRowAt ? lstOpciones entendemos que tiene valores, verdad? si no no hace nada

Comment: No, es como si no reconociera el delegado. No pasa por ningún evento de los del UITableViewDelegate. Es una lista dinámica, pero para probar he puesto valores fijos y sí los veo en el TableView ( los valores fijos y los dinámicos también), pero los eventos del UITableViewDelegate no saltan ninguno. Ese el problema, que no llega a pasar por el didSelectRowAt